# How does the final code-behind file look like in a typical MAUI app?

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, maui

What I've learnt from the [MAUI Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-user-interface-xaml/4-event-handling-xaml) is that the XAML file gets translated into equivalent C# code. This means, if I have a handler (say `BtnClick`) defined on a button (say `x:Name="BtnEx"`), somewhere while compilation, it'll get translated to `BtnEx.Clicked += BtnClick`. However, I also know that it is usually a standard to separate the handler from XAML so that one doesn't accidentally delete it, and define it in the code-behind instead. What I did:

```xml
<Button
    x:Name="CounterBtn"
    Text="Click me"
    SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
    Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Code-behind file:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CounterBtn.Clicked -= OnCounterClicked; // method definition omitted in MRE
}
```

The resultant code worked as if the handler had not subscribed meaning that `-=` was below the `+=` in the compiled code-behind. So where exactly will the `+=` lie in the compiler code-behind? Somewhere in the `ctor` after the `initializeComponent` call or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: The compiler creates a `XAML.g.cs` file containing the XAML to c# mappings

Comment: hmm... and how do I see this file?

Comment: Look through the build folders to find it

Comment: but.. isn't it an intermediate file?

Comment: Yes,  VS leaves behind tons of intermediate files during the build process

Comment: Also, is this why the classes in the code-behind files need to be `partial`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you are thinking. You won't find "equivalent c#", similar to what you would type if you typed it yourself.

AFAIK, xaml is handled the way it was in WPF: its compiled into a data "blob", which is processed by the Maui runtime.

All that shows up in c# is "mappings", so that c# compiler can connect c# references to xaml declarations.

"InitializeComponent" is in the .g.cs, but it does not reveal the xaml details, just the names of elements visible to c#.

"InitializeComponent" is when the equivalent of `+=` is run; but you can't see that.

Comment: but then why do I need to use partial classes in the code-behind file?

Comment: Even though `.g.cs` does not contain the info you are hoping for, it *is* compiled as part of the class. As mentioned, it contains the implementation of `InitializeComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the reason why you find *.g.cs* files in your projects *obj* folder. All of them are generated code files. They are created by the compiler when you build your project. The purpose of this files is to provide a generated implementation for partial classes or XAML-generated classes in your project.

For example, when you create a XAML-based user interface in a WPF, UWP or MAUI application, the XAML compiler generates *.g.cs* files that contain the generated code for the classes that correspond to the elements in the XAML markup. This generated code includes properties, event handlers, and other code necessary to interact with the user interface elements at runtime. Since the elements classes are defined partial, `InitializeComponent()` then is used to set everything up in your own implementations file (constructor).

In general, you should not make any changes to the *.g.cs* files, because any changes will be overwritten the next time you build the project. Instead, you should make changes to the related partial classes or XAML markup files and let the compiler generate the updated .g.cs files.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question correctly. Sorry my bad, I should have done a better job at asking. This thing is, that `-=` you see, is written in the code-behind file and not in the auto-generated one.

Comment: Not sure what's the problem. += is auto generated and executed in the InitializeComponent. -= then can be called by yourself afterwards. Does this not answer the question?